# Joomla - User Custom Fields (Required for user on frontend, but not required on backend)

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-users

I am using custom fields in the user section. I am needing to set this required for the front-end users when they are editing their profile, etc. This is working as intended, however, I am needing a way to create users on the backend - without having those fields required for the admin (on the backend).

Any thoughts how I can make those fields required only for the front-end users...and not for the admin in the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

i would say there are two options:

- build an override eg. own form for frontend
- add the required in the frontend with js (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

it depends on your usecase and „how often“ users will edit this form.
in both scenarios i would set the default state to not required.